# GmailApp/MailApp not working in Gsuite account, but works in normal account

Tags: google-apps-script

Below is the simple code I am using, which works fine when i use a normal google account, but when I use a g suite account I am getting the below error. How do I enable GmailApp or MailApp for my gsuite account ?

NOTE : I have already enabled Gmail API under advanced services

**Error:**

`[20-04-24 16:28:57:730 IST] TypeError: GmailApp.sendMail is not a function
    at myFunction(eMail:11:26)`

**Function:**

```
    function myFunction() {
        var email = "xyz@gmail.com";
        var name = "My Name";
        var subject = "Test Subject";
        var body = "Hi";

        GmailApp.sendMail(email,subject,body,{noreply:true});
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

### The correct name of the method is `GmailApp.sendEmail()`, not `sendMail()`

You can consult all the available methods for the class `GmailApp` [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)).